# How can I draw this figure in latex?

Tags: draw

How can I draw this figure using `LaTeX` code?

[image: e]

Comment: With use of the `tikz-cd` package should be easy. What you try so far? At list you should rotate image, that we can more easy read text on image ...

Comment: I looked at many question here but I could not find a question that contain a combination of a rectangle and triangle in one figure@Zarko

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As starting point based on one of my old answer. In diagram you need to insert correct variables:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\usepackage{amssymb}

    \begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large,
               every arrow/.append style = {-{Straight Barb[bend]}},
%               every label/.append style = {font=\normalsize}
               ]
                &   W \ar[d,"f"]
                      \ar[dl,bend right]
                      \ar[dr,bend  left]    &                   \\
B 
\ar[d,"xxx" ']  &   (A\times B)
                    \ar[l,"xxx" ']
                    \ar[r,"xxx"]
                    \ar[d,"xxx"]            &   A
                                                \ar[d,"xxx"]    \\
Y               &   X\times X       
                    \ar[l,"xxx" ']
                    \ar[r,"xxx"]            &   X               \\
\end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: **3.1415692mm** :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, huh, answer is based on one my old answer, where I also joked about the standalone border size ...  I overlooked this here. Hopefully is not to disturbing :-)

Comment: it is not compiling.

Comment: @Intuition, than your installation of LaTeX is ill.  Showed images is generated on my PC with use of the recent  MIkTeX and also tested on Overleaf. The MWE  certainly works. Please be more specific, what error you get?

Comment: It compiled thanks! :) and how can I put maps on the bended arrows?

Comment: I got it thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found this online editor, [Matcha](https://www.mathcha.io/), to be a very convenient tool for quickly typesetting images for Latex. It has an intuitive graphical interface that is quite pleasant to work with, and can be exported either as Tikz code or as an image.

For inspiration, here's a quick version of your image that I quickly whipped up.

[image: Mathcha example]

And the automatically-generated Tikz code:

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,211.1999969482422); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 211.1999969482422

%Curve Lines [id:da9024082468764771] 
\draw    (346.5,26.52) .. controls (380.29,28.17) and (406.02,55.37) .. (425.9,85.81) ;
\draw [shift={(426.8,87.2)}, rotate = 237.17000000000002] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da7724897046680852] 
\draw    (322.8,42.2) -- (323.75,82.2) ;
\draw [shift={(323.8,84.2)}, rotate = 268.64] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Curve Lines [id:da11287460295056873] 
\draw    (297.8,24.2) .. controls (270.65,24.87) and (238.13,56.88) .. (217.07,78.87) ;
\draw [shift={(215.8,80.2)}, rotate = 313.66999999999996] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da7338437223633045] 
\draw    (432.8,112.2) -- (433.75,152.2) ;
\draw [shift={(433.8,154.2)}, rotate = 268.64] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da025882083777394982] 
\draw    (324.8,111.2) -- (325.75,151.2) ;
\draw [shift={(325.8,153.2)}, rotate = 268.64] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da07040880715340103] 
\draw    (207.8,112.2) -- (208.75,152.2) ;
\draw [shift={(208.8,154.2)}, rotate = 268.64] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da1706718911066456] 
\draw    (287.8,97.2) -- (223.8,98.17) ;
\draw [shift={(221.8,98.2)}, rotate = 359.13] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da14767706108481948] 
\draw    (293.8,169.2) -- (226.8,169.2) ;
\draw [shift={(224.8,169.2)}, rotate = 360] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da6043606661934966] 
\draw    (363.8,99.2) -- (415.8,99.2) ;
\draw [shift={(417.8,99.2)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da07792819458867695] 
\draw    (356.8,169.2) -- (416.8,169.2) ;
\draw [shift={(418.8,169.2)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;


% Text Node
\draw (324,24) node    {$W$};
% Text Node
\draw (432,97) node    {$A$};
% Text Node
\draw (434,168) node    {$X$};
% Text Node
\draw (327,97) node    {$( A\times B)_{P}$};
% Text Node
\draw (208,98) node    {$B$};
% Text Node
\draw (209,168) node    {$Y$};
% Text Node
\draw (326,169) node    {$X\times Y$};
% Text Node
\draw (388,88) node    {$Pr_{A}$};
% Text Node
\draw (260,86) node    {$Pr_{B}$};
% Text Node
\draw (389,180) node    {$Pr_{X}$};
% Text Node
\draw (261,179) node    {$Pr_{Y}$};
% Text Node
\draw (453,128.4) node    {$in_{A}$};
% Text Node
\draw (189,129.4) node    {$in_{B}$};
% Text Node
\draw (351,130) node    {$in_{A\times B}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Very nice. The lines in the horizontal arrows are not quite straight, and the two arcs are not symmetrical. For me, this image is not quite ready for publication. I find the code complicated, and hard to edit.

Comment: The point is not to edit the code but to use the graphical interface. Lines can be made straight by holding the shift key. You can find out more by heading over to [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/).

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick