# Drawing an entangled commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the diagram I want to draw:

> [image]

My attempt so far:

```
\documentclass{amsart}[12]

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.3in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.4in, right=1.4in}
 %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
 \linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
\[ \begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-Stealth}]
  \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}  \rar \dar & \frac {(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb C}{(x_1, x_2, y) \sim (tx_1, tx_2, t^ky)}\lar \dar & \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \dar \\%
\mathbb C \rar \frac {(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\})}{(x_1, x_2) \sim (tx_1, tx_2)}& \lar  & \mathbb{C}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The rest of the arrows in my picture I do not know how to draw.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Hmm... you will get more help here if you (a) read the [docs](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en) (b) [have a go yourself](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), and (c) ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: You appear to have asked the same question back in 2020... [How can I draw this figure in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526758/how-can-i-draw-this-figure-in-latex)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos in general I know how to draw the diagram behind the curved arrows but the curved arrows above a commutative diagram, this is what I do not know how to do.

Comment: @Thruston  in general I know how to draw the diagram behind the curved arrows but the curved arrows above a commutative diagram, this is what I do not know how to do.

Comment: @Thruston I think the position of the arrows is different in my case here, also there are more types of arrows that should be drawn below each other .... in general for me this question is different that the one back in 2020

Comment: If you can do the diagram, you need to show compilable code for it, so that people can help with the arrows. Right now, your question is nothing more than a "do it for me" type question.

Comment: @hpekristiansen ok, I will, thanks for clarification.

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I do not see what makes it not compilable, may be the symbol for left arrow I am using, which is "lar"? frankly, I do not know how to correct this.

Comment: Do not look at the code. -your compiler will tell you why it is not compiling

Comment: sometimes the compilation errors are not understood to me. Since the question was not open, I guess I will post it again (after the edit) @hpekristiansen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning up the code is probably a good way to make it easier to understand. You need to load the package `tikz-cd` if you want to use the `tikzcd` environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}[12]
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.3in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.4in, right=1.4in}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-Stealth}]
    \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} 
    \arrow[r]\arrow[d] & 
    \frac{(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb C}{(x_1, x_2, y) \sim (tx_1, tx_2, t^ky)}
    \arrow[d] &
    \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} 
    \arrow[l]\arrow[d] \\
    %
    \mathbb C 
    \arrow[r] & 
    \frac {(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\})}{(x_1, x_2) \sim (tx_1, tx_2)} & 
    \mathbb{C} 
    \arrow[l] \\
    %
    &
    \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} 
    \arrow[d]\arrow[luu, bend left]\arrow[ruu, bend right] &
    \\
    %
    &
    \mathbb{C} 
    \arrow[luu, bend left]\arrow[ruu, bend right]
    \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

This should give you the following to start with:

[image]

Comment: What about the maps below the arrows and the stuff written in red?

Comment: Since I am not able to read the handwriting in the drawing you provided, I was only able to provide something to start with. But you can probably add those using the same logic. You can add labels to the arrows, for example with `\arrow[direction, "label"]`.

Comment: Yeah I know this, but how to put arrow above another arrow?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot figure out what exactly you imagine. From the picture you provided, I think that you probably want something like labeln attached to the arrows, such as `\arrow[r, "{u \mapsto (u,i)}"']` or `\arrow[l, "{v \mapsfrom (v,i)}"]` (for `\mapsfrom`, you will probably need to load another package). Maybe you can edit your question or ask a new one and more concretely tell us how exactly you want to place the arrows?

Comment: I got you ok, thank you!